# gRPC Bidirectional Streaming Rate Limit Istio

Tags: grpc, istio, envoyproxy

Istio supports [Rate Limits](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/policy-enforcement/rate-limit/) for http requests. The documentation suggests that this also works for gRPC endpoints.

What is unclear is how it behaves when I have a bidirectional streaming request, for example:

```
rpc PingPong(stream Ping) returns (stream Pong) {}
```

If I have a limit of 100 requests per minute, how does that work? In other words, if I had a client open a `PingPong` rpc connection, and try to send 200 `Ping`s in a minute, would the rate limit kick in, or would it not kick in as there was only one stream opened?